# Delete all files in a directory without deleting others with similar file type endings

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Lets say I have a directory that looks something like this:

```
--FolderParent
  --FolderChild1
    --File1.abc
    --File2.abcd
  --FolderChild2
    --File1.abc
    --File2.abcd
```

I would like to delete File.abc without deleting File2.abcd. I have tried running these commands inside FolderParent

```
del /S *.abc
```

and

```
del /S *".abc"
```

but those both also delete File2.abcd.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the majority of the built-in commands and utilities, use the 8.3 names. You could disable the default setting of using them in Windows, *(however)*, it will not remove any 'short' names already defined at that time.

The simplest way therefore, is to use a built-in utility which ignores 8.3 naming, `where.exe`:

In [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```sh
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Set "PATHEXT=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R ".\FolderParent" "*.abc" 2^>NUL') Do @Del /A /F "%G"
```

Or in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Set "PATHEXT=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R ".\FolderParent" "*.abc" 2^>NUL') Do @Del /A /F "%%G"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of work is required to confirm the file doesn't have a long extension

use the `*` wildcard in a `dir /b` command, pipe it to `findstr` with `/R` regex with `$` eol flag. capture the result of these steps using a for loop, and `del` the result.

Double all `%` characters for batch file.

```bat
For /f "delims=" %G in ('dir /b/s/a:-D "*.abc" ^| findstr /r "[\.][a][b][c]$"')Do del "%G" 2> nul
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell does not have some of the anomalies of cmd.exe. When you are sure the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` command.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'C:\ParentFolder' -Filter '*.abc' | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

If you must run from cmd.exe:

```
powershell -Nologo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'C:\ParentFolder' -Filter '*.abc' | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by PowerShell not having anomalies, had that been true, you would be able to use `Remove-Item -Path .\FolderParent -Filter *.abc -Recurse -Force`, but as we know `Remove-Item` is, and has for some time been, broken when using it directly with its `-Recurse` property. Also technically, it is simply that `-Filter` is not using 8.3 naming; if you were to replace that with `-Include`, it would revert to picking up the `.abcd` files too.